# Access ref on different component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am adding the slider menu [react-native-drawer-menu](https://github.com/Tinysymphony/react-native-drawer-menu) to my app in app.js

```
<Drawer
      style={styles.container}
      drawerWidth={300}
      drawerContent={drawerContent}
      type={Drawer.types.Overlay}
      customStyles={{drawer: styles.drawer}}
      drawerPosition={Drawer.positions.Left}
      onDrawerOpen={() => {console.log('Drawer is opened');}}
      onDrawerClose={() => {console.log('Drawer is closed')}}
      easingFunc={Easing.ease}
    >
      <Provider store={store}>
      <MenuContext>
        <RootContainer />
      </MenuContext>
      </Provider>

    </Drawer>
```

In root container I create the app-navigator and load the first view `WelcomeContainer`. Every thing is working fine and I am able to swipe in `welcomeContainer` to open the menu.

[image]

Now I tried to also open the menu when I click on the Menu Icon on the header. The header is created on the `WelcomeContainer`. This is the code

```
render() {
    const {language} = this.props
    const {navigate, setParams} = this.props.navigation
    return (
      <Drawer ref={drawer => this.drawer = drawer}>
      <View style={ styles.container }>
      <Header

  leftComponent = {
  { 
    icon: 'menu', 
    color: '#5c72b0', 
    onPress: () => this.drawer.openDrawer()
  } 
}
  centerComponent={<ChangeLanguage />} 
  rightComponent={<HeaderUserInformation />} 
  outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#eee9e9' }}
/>
```

Unfortunately this dose not work properly. This is how the slider menu looks like:

[image]

So swiping is working fine but not manually opening the menu. Do you have any idea about the problem? I have the feeling that by clicking, I am opening the menu on the wrong reference of drawer, but I am not able to locate the problem.

Comment: Looks like you are using react-navigation in your app. Why don't you use DrawerNavigator? It will be much more easier for you to setup your app.

Comment: Do you mean this one https://github.com/ilansas/react-native-navigation-drawer ?I tried to use this one but I think the code is old and I got a lot of problems with my react native version.

Comment: no I mean [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer)

Comment: Ok I will maybe try it